# Changing the titles within a raster stack

Tags: r, plot, raster, r-raster

I had created a raster stack when plotted looks like this:
[image]

I would like to change the titles on each of these graphs, and add a main title to it.

```
levelplot(rs, main = "MD13U0001", col.regions=rev(terrain.colors(6)), names.attr=c("LoCoH", "Elevation"))
```

When I try using the function `levelplot` it gives me this:
[image]

It puts both plots into the same scale, but gives me what I want in relation to the titles. Is there a better function that will give me the titles, but not keep the scales separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example data

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))[[1:2]]
```

Set layer names and default plot

```
names(s) <- c("Apple", "Mango")
plot(s, cex.main=.8)
```

Some example customization

```
par(mar=c(3,3,5,5), mfrow=c(1,2))
for (i in 1:2) {
    plot(s[[i]], cex.axis=.75, las=1)
    title(names(s)[i], line=0.5, cex.main=0.8)
}
text(-40, 100, "These are my maps", xpd=NA, cex=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example for levelplot instead?